# Basic partial fractions issue

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

I've been starting to get the hang on partial fractions, whilst I've been able to do most of the basic ones, this kept causing some issues so I assumed:

1. I'm using the wrong method
2. I'm converting values when I shouldn't be

---

Before going on I'll post the question:

(a) Express $\frac{x^2 + 6x + 7}{(x - 3) (x^2 +2x + 2))}$ in partial fractions

---

After seeing that this question only held 3 marks out of 100 I thought that it was relatively simple. However the values that I was receiving were nothing like what I would normally get. I could post my results but honestly I wrote so many it's irrelevant.

What I initially did was turn the $(x^2 +2x +2)$ into $(x+2)(x+1)$ which would leave us with:
$$\frac{x^2 + 6x + 7}{(x - 3) (x+2)(x+1)}$$

From there I used the usual method by placing the equation like so:
$$\frac{A}{(x-3)}+\frac{B}{(x+2)}+\frac{C}{(x+1)}$$

After that I found the LCM and starts cutting off terms by replacing $x$ with a specific value:
$$A(x+2)(x+1) + B(x-3)(x+1) + C(x-3)(x+2)$$

---

The rest is basically history, I can barely understand what I was even trying to do. Feel free to guide me to the right direction

---

### Mistakes pointed out:

1. My factorisation is incorrent for $$x^2 + 2x +2 = (x + 2)(x+1)$$

---

### Extra Attempts

My second attempt was done using the method for quadratic factors inside the denominator. So it's now:
$$\frac{A}{(x-3)}+\frac{Bx+C}{(x^2 + 2x + 2)}$$

From here on I think I'm meant to find the LCM by doing the following:
$$(Bx+C)(x-3) + A(x^2 + 2x +2)$$

I then substitute $x$ with 3 in order to find the value of $A$ which would end up like so:
$$16 + 6x = 17A$$

After that I'm not entirely sure if it's correct(highly doubt so)

---

However not much has changed in terms of getting a viable answer

Comment: $(x+2)(x+1)=x^2+3x+2$ so your initial factorisation is incorrect

Comment: @Mufasa Woops you are right, my bad! That's what I get for not actually testing it beforehand. I've went ahead and pointed out the mistake in the original post. I'll give it another go and see what I can come up with.

Comment: It would help if you showed us your steps so that we can spot where you may have made a mistake

Comment: I have posted them in the question Mufasa it's in the beginning. However Mary Star pointed out a critical mistake and provided me with a good template to work on. So I'll start off by working it out using her answer

Comment: I meant the steps for your Extra Attempts where you broke it down into the correct partial fractions

Comment: @Mufasa - Oh right sorry! Will post them in a second

Comment: I've gone ahead and posted how far I went before not quite getting what I'm required to do as what I've got so far doesn't seem like something I could work with.

Comment: Your item number 2 under mistakes is NOT a mistake - both forms of partial fractions will lead to the correct answer - they are just using different symbols to represent the constants

Comment: @Mufasa But wouldn't the values for A, B & C then be different?

Comment: $\frac{A_1}{x-3}+\frac{B_1x+C_1}{x^2+2x+2}$ and $\frac{A_2x+B_2}{x^2+2x+2}+\frac{C_2}{x-3}$ will both lead to the correct answer but the answers will be related: $A_1=C_2$, $B_1=A_2$, $C_1=B_2$

Comment: @Mufasa Oh alright that does make more sense then. Thanks alot Mufasa

Comment: When you put in $x=3$, you can't get an equation that still has $x$ in it. You should be able to get the value of $A$. Then put in some other simple values for $x$, say, $x=0$ and $x=1$, to get two equations for $B$ and $C$.

Comment: When you used $x=3$ you forgot to replace the $x$ in $16+6x=17A$ which would have led you to $16+18=17A\implies 34=17A$

Comment: Actually for learning reasons I'm going to go ahead and rework all of this using multiple methods. I'd like to say a big thank you for all the help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2+2x+2=0 \Rightarrow \Delta=4-4 \cdot 2=4-8=-4<0$$

So it has no real roots.

Therefore, to express $\frac{x^2 + 6x + 7}{(x - 3) (x^2 +2x + 2)}$ in partial fractions we do the following:

$$\frac{x^2 + 6x + 7}{(x - 3) (x^2 +2x + 2)}=\frac{A}{x-3}+\frac{Bx+c}{x^2+2x+2}$$

(The polynomial at the numerator has to be one degree smaller than the degree of the polynomial of the denominator.)

**EDIT:**

$$\frac{x^2 + 6x + 7}{(x - 3) (x^2 +2x + 2)}=\frac{A}{x-3}+\frac{Bx+c}{x^2+2x+2} \\ \Rightarrow \frac{x^2 + 6x + 7}{(x - 3) (x^2 +2x + 2)}=\frac{A(x^2+2x+2)+(Bx+C)(x-3)}{(x-3)(x^2+2x+2)}  \\ \Rightarrow x^2+6x+7=Ax^2+2Ax+2A+Bx^2-3Bx+Cx-3C \\ \Rightarrow  x^2+6x+7=(A+B)x^2+(2A-3B+C)x+(2A-3C) $$ Now you have to solve the following system:

$$A+B=1 \\ 2A-3B+C=6 \\ 2A-3C=7$$

Comment: Oh alright, I had the same idea but I executed it in the wrong many. This is very helpful, I *should* be able to work it out like this. Thanks Mary

Comment: If I may ask you to give my original post another look under *Extra Attempts* to see what I must have done. Sorry!

Comment: I added some more information at my answer!!

Comment: Oh wow thanks alot! This makes alot more sense now